# Use animation to scroll bottom of textView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextview

My code right animates scrolling down but just stops where I put the y coordinate. I would like the animation to continue to the very bottom of the textview.

```
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 9) { 


        self.textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollRangeToVisible`.

Playground example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

func scrollTextViewToBottom(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if(textView.text.characters.count > 0 ) {
        guard let text = textView.text else {
            return
        }
        let bottom = NSRange(location: text.characters.count - 1, length: 1)
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
    }
}

var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300))
textView.text = "start long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts long texts end"

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = textView

scrollTextViewToBottom(textView)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can scroll to the bottom of a `UIScrollView` (`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`).

Manually animate the content offset (allows you to use a custom animation) :

```
let textView = UITextView()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 9) {
    let contentSize = textView.contentSize
    let contentInset = textView.contentInset
    let textViewBounds = textView.bounds
    let newContentOffset = CGPoint(
        x: contentSize.width + contentInset.right - textViewBounds.width,
        y: contentSize.height + contentInset.bottom - textViewBounds.height
    )
    textView.contentOffset = newContentOffset
}
```

Or use the `scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:)` method (easier but uses built-in animation):

```
let textView = UITextView()

let contentSize = textView.contentSize
let contentInset = textView.contentInset
let bottomRightPosition = CGPoint(
    x: contentSize.width + contentInset.right,
    y: contentSize.height + contentInset.bottom
)
textView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: bottomRightPosition, size: .zero), animated: true)
```

Both these examples will scroll until the bottom right point of your textView is visible (textViews usually don't scroll horizontally, so that's equivalent to scrolling to the bottom).